# java.lang.NullPointerException while trying to deploy ExperienceBundle

Tags: lightning-experience, lightning-community, experience-bundle

I'm getting multiple errors depending on Retrieve API version

When retrieving ExperienceBundle from source with v58

[image]

I'll get the error "You seem to be missing the property devName".

[image]

When retrieved with v60, xml file fires a java.lang.NullPointerException

[image]

[image]

How to avoid the nullpointerexception?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar error, **If you are using a AURA site**, then i would recommend that you need to use **SiteDotCom** to extract the **site_name1** metadata as part of the experience site deployment to any other org.

This new feature to have it as in a readable format, i am not sure but it is not working throwing lots of the error while deployment.

I was using **Experience Bundle** only, but now i used the **legacy** way as we used to deployed the **communities** and it worked without any error it is deployed.