java.lang.NullPointerException error while Salesforce Deployment Experience Site
When i try to deploy ExperienceBundle to higher orgs I'm receiving the following error. No other details are available. How to overcome or find the exact issue in this case.


Contact Technical Support. There's approximately a 0% chance we can help you with this, as it is a bug in Salesforce; you should generally never see a java.lang.* exception.

Does this help? (https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/419354/java-lang-nullpointerexception-while-trying-to-deploy-experiencebundle)
